# Can a DataGridView have popup editors for cells like a PropertyGrid does?

Tags: c#, winforms

A complex property in a PropertGrid can have a button with "..." which shows an editor in a separate window.  Does the DataGridView have built in support for this, and if not how can I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if it has built in support for the "..."  extender.. But you could accomplish something similar if needed. I found an article where someone needed that functionality. All the code is posted [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/051887c6-2d87-4361-a5a1-cd5213609673/how-to-popup-text-edit-window-in-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols) on answer #1...

Comment: Dont have VS with me or i'd go check around